# How to show local images from the device in cordova based IOS application

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, html5-filesystem

Am trying to show locally saved image in my IOS cordova application.
image path looks like this

> var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F6BC9B7B-0D2F-46D3-996E-A35352901ED/Documents/folder/MyImageName.png

How can i display this image in a `<img/>` .

i have tried to give same url and `file:/// {path}` as img src
but its not working.

i have installed `cordova-plugin-file`plugin  and tried to access local file system using `requestFileSystem` method but its not working for me.

Comment: What is generating that path? Are you using a plugin, etc.? Some code would be nice to see.

Comment: this is the image path :
var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F6BC9B7B-0D2F-46D3-996E-A35352901ED/Documents/folder/MyImageName.png

Comment: Yes, but where you getting the path from? I'm assuming a plugin, but it would be nice to see the code you're using for this particular process.

You can try using "cdvfile://localhost/persistent/folder/MyImageName.png".

Side note: Don't store absolute paths; everything prior to /Documents can change whenever iOS desires. You'll want to store relative paths or cdvfile:// paths instead.